# Rstudio crashing on simple lm loop - concurrent sessions?

Tags: crash, rstudio, lm

I'm experiencing intermittent hard Rstudio crashes.  As the hard crash seems to occur during the progress window of the following lm code, I believe it is here that the issue resides.

```
  OUT <- period %>% 
    group_by(xy) %>% 
    do(model = lm(Z ~ Y, data = .))
```

This being applied on a list of files.  It is not specific to the file, as I can pick this process up on the 'crash' file and it will run without issue.  It will often run without issue for several hundred files in the list.

Now I am running this by invoking multiple Rstudio/R instances (from start menu) and running the same code in these instances.   Even when running two instances, one will crash, the other eventually will as well, which has me wondering if its really related to the concurrent instances.  I am not using an R project file,  not using 'sessions'

I could run literally hundreds of these concurrently and not come close to maxing out memory/ram.

Windows 10 pro
Rstudio 2022.12.0 Build 353
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting

Question
Is this related to the way I am invoking multiple Rstudio sessions?  I do this frequently and dont usually have an issue.

Any other ideas?

I have not tried a solution

Comment: What if you try it outside of R Studio?

Comment: Good question, I'm trying that now